# For voice editing, should I change the cutoff frequency with each note pitch?

Tags: editing

I'm trying to remove the spaniard accent in a short phrase:

- [Original](https://soundcloud.com/rraallvv/la-casa-del-gitano-es_es)
- [Edited](https://soundcloud.com/rraallvv/la-casa-del-gitano-es_la)

It turns out that removing the soft growling sound at the beginning of the word **gitano**, and using a low pass filter for the sound **s** in **casa**, gave a convincing hispano-american accent.

The problem is that if I try to apply the same filter for notes with different pitches, I might end up with something that could sound artificial, so I was wondering what criteria should I use to "transpose" the frequency cutoff for the filter that need to be used for each different note pitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a simple experiment to find out. Sing the same phrase in two (or more) different pitches, isolate the 's' and play them next to each other.

My suspicion is that they will sound very similar but it's better to check. If so, you won't need to transpose your filter.

You should also try using a de-esser. They make 's' sound like 'th' if you compress too much.

Comment: I just found out that Adobe Audition has a de-esser, I'll try what you suggested then. Hmm... is there a technical word to describe the soft growling at the beginning of "gitano", it sounds a bit like when someone is making a gargle. Maybe there is process already that could remove that too.

Comment: I don't know if there is a word for that but as it is the first letter, I would try a very fast fade in. The way I hear it, what differentiates the sharp 'g' sound from the 'w' sound (as in **w**ater) is the attack time. You could use a compressor to do this automatically but I wouldn't suggest it because it will affect every attack and not just the ones in 'g'.